# How to know what button is clicked when opening modalBottomSheet for changing his value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem in JetpackCompose,
i have some boxes in my screen, and for each boxes, it hide or open the ModalBottomSheet.
What I want to do is that I want to change the value of the box I clicked when I'm choosing a proposition in the list in my ModalBottomSheet.

I can't figure it out, how I can achieve this.

Comment: You've specified too much of code and it's not buildable(first error is `App.Photo.packageName` missing). Please remove as much not needed code as you can and provide buildable sample of your problem

Comment: The question isn't clear. Do you think `ViewModel` concept is what you are looking for? [Link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state)

Comment: i edited the code, now, you can use this for build.

Comment: @SreekantShenoy no, that's not what I am talking about, image 8 buttons and 1 ModalBottomSheet.
Each button has a value like "com.android.camera", and I want to change this value.
What I have done is that I created a MOdalBottomSheet with a LazyList inside with many propositions.
Now imagine I click on the button "photo", the BottomSheet is open, and I click on "camera45" in the list. how can I change the value of the variable in the button "photo" when I click on "camera45".

Comment: Yes he is actually looking for the concept of unidirectional data flow, achieved with the help of a viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always store such states inside a viewmodel. You can use state hosting to pass callback events up to the viewmodel. See this is a conceptual problem. You should consider taking the state codelab for Jetpack compose to understand this. Concepts like unidirectional data flow and all. It sounds pretty mumbo-jumbo but is fairly easy and straightforward to understand.

I'll see if I can edit this answer later with an explanation. Till then, please take the codelab

Comment: Just transfer all those mutable state declarations to your viewmodel. Then create methods like onPhotoChanged(). Then pass these methods inside the Composables as parameters, entering new values through there.

Comment: This way, events reach up to the viewmodel, which passes down state to the Composables